# Help Center wording implies moderators are elected even on Beta sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, wording, privileges-page

In the Help Center, under the "[Access Moderator Tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)" privilege (2k/10k reputation), the wording under "What is Moderation" makes a clear reference to *elected* community moderators:

> ...which collectively allow you to help **the elected community moderators** in monitoring the site and helping to clean up messes.

This exact same wording is used on beta sites (in which community moderators are *not* elected, rather they are [appointed pro tempore](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)) as well as graduated sites (which actually *do* elect community moderators).

Maybe it's a bit nitpicky, but it'll annoy me forever now that I've noticed it.

Answer (score 1):

I've changed this phrasing on the `/help/privileges/moderator-tools` page from "elected community moderators" to "site moderators", and added a link to the "Who are the site moderators, and what is their role here?" help center page (`/help/site-moderators`).

Be annoyed no more. :)

Comment: Though technically, pro tempore mods are elected now. Eventually, as old beta sites graduate us MSE mods will be the last appointed mods left :D

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: True, but I figured I'd keep it generic. :)